# first non NaN element value and index in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to obtain value and index of first non-NaN element from each column of a matrix in the matlab.

In a separate problem--- There are few columns that does not have NaN. So in that case-- I would like to extract value and index of first non-NaN element from each column and otherwise first element of each column if column does not contain NaN.

Can anybody help regarding these two problems?

Comment: The second part, as it stands now, is included in the first. What's the output for a column that has all NaNs?

Comment: @Luis Mendo: Thanks a lot! What if I want the index of  the last element from each such column that contains all NaNs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index is easily obtained with the second output of [`max`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html). The value can be found from that index using [`sub2ind`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) or computing the corresponding linear index manually.

To return a different index in columns that contain all `NaN`, use the first output of `max` to detect that situation and change the result for those columns.

Let `x` denote your matrix. Then:

```
[m, index]  = max(~isnan(x), [], 1);
value = x(index + (0:size(x,2)-1)*size(x,1));
        %// or equivalently x(sub2ind(size(x), index, 1:size(x,2)))
index(~m) = size(x, 1); %// return last index for columns that have all NaN
```

#### Example

```
x = [  8    NaN     3    NaN
      NaN     4     5    NaN];
```

produces

```
index =
     1     2     1     2
value =
     8     4     3   NaN
```

Comment: How can I modify this code when-- 1. I want the index of the first element for a column that has all NaNs and 2. I want the index  of the last element for a column that does not contain any NaN (column with all "No-NaNs"). Can you please help?

Comment: @Aditya I'm away from computer now. Please ping me again next week and I'll take a look at it

Comment: Sure.Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Aditya I think this does what you want: `x = [8 NaN 3 NaN;NaN 4 5 NaN]; ix = ~isnan(x); [m, index]  = max(ix, [], 1); value = x(index + (0:size(x,2)-1)*size(x,1)); index(all(ix,1)) = size(x,1);`

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for this!