# How to find the frist occurrence of Nan value in a matlab code (m file)?

Tags: matlab, iteration, nan

I have a Matlab code (m-file) that contains many matrices and vectors. I'm doing some calculations and iterative solution. Of course some matrices depend on others, however, doing iterative calculation making it difficult for me to identify which which matrix has the first occurrence of a Nan value.

**Is there any command or debugger that I can include at the top of my code to till me when exactly the first NaN value is generated?**

(by when I mean at which step). or something that can stop my code once the first value of NaN is generated and probably help to find the related matrix/vector.

I have been searching the internet for possible solutions, however, all what I found, if I have **know** matrix, then I can find the index of the first NaN, but this is not my question.
Related issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36121739/first-non-nan-element-value-and-index-in-matlab) and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/389525-simple-method-for-finding-if-any-nan-values-occur-in-a-matrix), aside from many on Mathwork.

Comment: Try [`dbstop if naninf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html). Is that what you want?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'll try it out, it might help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I like using *conditional breakpoints*. Right click on the line in the editor, where you want to stop for debugging and choose "Set Conditional Breakpoint..."

[image: set a conditional breakpoint]

A window pops up, where you can type MATLAB code, which returns a boolean scalar

[image: configuration window]

for example, you can test if `any` element in the variable `x` `isnan`.